# Trying to calculate holiday pay from the Gross Pay

Tags: if-statement, percentage

I was wondering if anyone can help.

I am trying to calculate the holiday pay and pension, using the if format.

So basically I want to calculate the holiday (3%) if the gross pay is above £175

```
var NI = form.getColumnTotalOfField("NI")
if(form.getColumnTotalOfField("GrossPayDP") > 175)
{
    form.getColumnTotalOfField("NI15.05.175") * 3 / 100;
}
```